# Reset text in textfield of UISearchBar when X button is clicked, but not resign firstresponder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a view with a UISearchBar in it. However, when the "X" button in the searchbar is clicked, it removes the keyboard but doesn't remove the text in the textfield of the searchbar. What I want is this: When the user clicks the x button, the text in the textfield is reset but the keyboard stays up.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

This seems to do the trick for me.
Make sure your View Controller is a UISearchBarDelegate

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: this does not fire when the little "X"-button in the textfield is clicked. This one is only fired if the search bar displays a cancel button next to the text field.

Comment: This isn't what the question asks for. The X button is not the cancel button, it's the clear button

Answer (score 7):

Just set the text to **nil** in *searchBarCancelButtonClicked* delegate method :

```
searchBar.text = nil;
```

Comment: this does not fire when the little "X"-button in the textfield is clicked. This one is only fired if the search bar displays a cancel button next to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

to clear text use this  `searchBar.text = @"";`

Answer (score -1):

try implementing `UISearchBarDelegate`'s method `-(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` and return `NO` as the result.

E.g.:

```
    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        return NO;
    }
```